# SSIS - Vendor supplies 12 xml tables, we only need 3 how to remove or ignore extra tables

Tags: ssis-2012

I have found this to be a bug, however, I need to remove the warnings
[SSIS.Pipeline] Warning: The output column "x" on output "y" and component "z" is not subsequently used in the Data Flow task.
How do I accomplish this ?
Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

The vendor supplied .xsd contains definitions for 12 xml tables.
We only use 3 but SSIS is complaining with warning message:
[SSIS.Pipeline] Warning: The output column....
Most of what I've seen on web search, say to direct these input streams to a union-all task, haven't seen a good exxample of this, so looking for other
methods.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may need to open the XMLSource component and, on the columns tab, uncheck the columns that you are not using later on the datafow; this will clear the warning messages.